# Rotating axis labels in R

Tags: r, label, axis, plot

How do I make a (bar) plot's y axis labels parallel to the X axis instead of parallel to the Y axis?

Comment: See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but try setting `las=1`.  Here's an example:

```
require(grDevices)
tN <- table(Ni <- stats::rpois(100, lambda=5))
r <- barplot(tN, col=rainbow(20), las=1)
```

[image: output]

That represents the style of axis labels. (0=parallel, 1=all horizontal, 2=all perpendicular to axis, 3=all vertical)

Comment: it works, but it trim labels. So additional options may be required.

Comment: Is there an easy way to rotate the axis ticks labels? E.g. if I have larger numbers as axis tick labels, it is nice to have them rotated by around 45 degrees to strike a good balance between readability (horizontal) and space efficiency (vertical).

Answer (score 96):

Use `par(las=1)`.

See `?par`:

```
las
numeric in {0,1,2,3}; the style of axis labels.
0: always parallel to the axis [default],
1: always horizontal,
2: always perpendicular to the axis,
3: always vertical.
```

Comment: Is there a way to set it so that only the x axis labels are perpendicular to the axis?

Comment: Te style can be set for each axis separately, e.g. `plot(1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n"); axis(1, las=2); axis(2, las=1)`

Comment: always backup par before doing any changes like that: old.par <- par(no.readonly=T)   :-)

Answer (score 23):

As **Maciej Jończyk** mentioned, you may also need to increase margins

```
par(las=2)
par(mar=c(8,8,1,1)) # adjust as needed
plot(...)
```

Answer (score 14):

You need to use theme() function as follows rotating x-axis labels by 90 degrees:

```
ggplot(...)+...+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Comment: should be 90 degrees

Answer (score 2):

First, create the data for the chart

```
H <- c(1.964138757, 1.729143013,    1.713273714,    1.706771799,    1.67977205)
M <- c("SP105", "SP30", "SP244", "SP31",    "SP147")
```

Second, give the name for a chart file

```
png(file = "Bargraph.jpeg", width = 500, height = 300)
```

Third, Plot the bar chart

```
barplot(H,names.arg=M,ylab="Degree ", col= rainbow(5), las=2, border = 0, cex.lab=1, cex.axis=1, font=1,col.axis="black")
title(xlab="Service Providers", line=4, cex.lab=1)
```

Finally, save the file

```
dev.off()
```

Output:

[image]