# Change direction labels of axes in plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot

In drawing a plot with R, the X-axe labels are horizontal, I want a vertical labels.Is it possible?

For example, such this:

[image: Fig1]

Comment: Check `?par`, option `las`.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828742/rotating-axis-labels-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of rotating isduplicated ad is answered many times here. But I add this answer for 2 reasons :

1. the ticks labels are long so we need to add margins at bottom
2. the ticks labels are a little bit complicated and created using `plotmath`

[image]
This is the code:

```
par(mar=c(8, 4, 2, 4))
plot(1:5,1:5,xaxt='n',frame.plot=FALSE,xlab='')
expr1 <- expression(L[2](delta[J~S](X,W),theta))
expr2 <- expression(L[4](delta[J~S](X,W),theta))
axis(1,las=2,labels=c(expr1,expr1),at=2:3,pos=1)
arrows(0,1,5,1)
```