# using text() in R

Tags: r, text, axis

I am trying to re-label and adjust my x-axis in a barplot using text() in R. Some bits I have managed to fugure out myself already, but now I am stuck with the following issue: I would love to increase the space between my labels in order to fit them nicely under the bar they belong to. Here's what I (amateurishly) have come up with so far:

```
    lab<-c("Morning (PT)", "Evening (PT)",
           "Morning (LT)", "Evening (LT)",
           "Morning (total)", "Evening (total)")
    barplot(data, names.arg=data$period, 
            col=c("darkorange1",  "firebrick3", "darkolivegreen4", "goldenrod1"), 
            main="", ylab="(%)", xaxt = "n", xlim=c(0,10))
    text(c(1,1,1,1,1,1), labels = lab, srt = 45, 
         adj = c(1,2), xpd = TRUE, cex=.7)
```

[image: Plot]

After spending hours trying to unsuccessfully understand the par() argument, I was wondering if someone might be able to help me on this. Maybe there is a nice and simple solution which I have failed to see?

Thanks a lot in advance for any tipps!
Daniela

Comment: For barplots with long labels, you can use horizontal bars (since the labels are horizontal, they are also much easier to read).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Vincent Zoonekynd, you can just rotate the x labels using the `las` argument (see [rotating axis labels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828742/rotating-axis-labels-in-r)). I don't know exactly how your data looks like so I made a simplified example:

```
lab <- c("Morning (PT)", "Evening (PT)",
           "Morning (LT)", "Evening (LT)",
           "Morning (total)", "Evening (total)")

data <- data.frame(numbers=c(1,2,1,2,2,1), period=lab)
par(mar=c(7, 4, 4, 2))
barplot(data$numbers,names.arg=lab, col="darkorange1", main="", ylab="(%)", las=2)
```

[image]

If you want different angles for the labels, you can use `text`, see this post: [Rotating x axis labels in R for barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286473/rotating-x-axis-labels-in-r-for-barplot).

Does this help you?