# r does not show specified dates on x-axis

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

I used the following to generate a histogram

```
mi= 1425168014.519
ma= 1427919527.540
b=mi+rnorm(2000,sd=1)*(ma-mi)
hist(as.POSIXct(b, origin="1970-01-01"),breaks=50, freq = TRUE,axes=F)
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-01"), by="1 days"), format="%d %b %y")
```

But the specified dates are not shown in entirety. It only shows as minor ticks. I want it to be shown as labels.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably need to make your viewing window bigger- I at least saw two dates when I ran your code. Second, you will want your axis labels to be perpendicular to the axis, which you can do with the `las` option ([relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828742/rotating-axis-labels-in-r)).

```
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-01"), by="1 days"), 
  format="%d %b %y", las=2)
```

If you do this, all of your labels will be on top of each other, so you will probably want to increase your interval to something larger, like 10 days.

```
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-04-01"), by="10 days"), 
format="%d %b %y", las=2)
```