# Rotate labels for histogram bars - shown via: labels = TRUE

Tags: r, histogram

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317948/how-to-label-histogram-bars-with-data-values-or-percents-in-r) is shown how to label histogram bars with data values or percents using `labels = TRUE`. Is it also possible to rotate those labels? My goal is to rotate them to 90 degrees because now the labels over bars overrides each other and it is unreadable.

PS: please note that my goal is not to rotate y-axis labels as it is shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828742/rotating-axis-labels-in-r)

Comment: @jeremycg this is not a duplicate of mentioned question. This question ask how to rotate labels for each bar. Linked question asks how to rotate y-axis labels.

Comment: My guess is that you'll need to plot the text labels yourself (using `text(..., srt=90)`). It may help to know that `hist(...)` provides output that tells you the `mids` for each bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mtcars`, here's one brute-force solution (though it isn't very brutish):

```
h <- hist(mtcars$mpg)
maxh <- max(h$counts)
strh <- strheight('W')
strw <- strwidth(max(h$counts))
hist(mtcars$mpg, ylim=c(0, maxh + strh + strw))
text(h$mids, strh + h$counts, labels=h$counts, adj=c(0, 0.5), srt=90)
```

The `srt=90` is the key here, rotating 90 degrees counter-clockwise (anti-clockwise?).

`maxh`, `strh`, and `strw` are used (1) to determine how much to extend the y-axis so that the text is not clipped to the visible figure, and (2) to provide a small pad between the bar and the start of the rotated text. (The first reason could be mitigated by `xpd=TRUE` instead, but it *might* impinge on the main title, and will be a factor if you set the top margin to 0.)

[image]

Note: if using density instead of frequency, you should use `h$density` instead of `h$counts`.

**Edit**: changed `adj`, I always forget the x/y axes on it stay relative to the text regardless of rotation.

**Edit #2**: changing the first call to `hist` so the string height/width are calculate-able. Unfortunately, plotting twice is required in order to know the actual height/width.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I run your code I get: `> strh <- strheight('W')
Error in strheight("W") : plot.new has not been called yet`

Comment: Note that if you are confident enough about the size of the labels, you can forego the first call to `hist` and use another mechanism. This double-plot is to get relatively accurate measures of string sizes on the plot window.